# Google Tag Manager SDKs - implementing Adobe Analytics?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

I'm working on a project to deliver Android and iOS native apps. Unfortunately the company that we're delivering this for has multiple stakeholders around the globe who use different analytics solutions.

This means we have to implement GA, Omniture (Adobe Analytics) plus at least two others! Rolling four analytics tracking solutions on every event/screen is a nightmare scenario for the native apps devs, so we're looking at using a Tag Manager. Adobe's DTM does not have an SDK, so that puts us back into GTM land.

However I have not been able to find good direction on using GTM's "custom" function within an iOS or Android container using the SDKs.

The question: has anyone had experience calling Adobe Analytics using GTM for iOS or Android using the SDKs? If so, how difficult was it? Are there any tricks/tips you can offer?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at a service like segment.com (no affiliation) ? The idea seems to be that you implement their SDK and they distribute data to various tracking solutions (their integrations page specifically mentions Adobe Analytics and Google Analytics, and a lot more).

Comment: Thanks. That looks like a pretty neat solution, however given the client has almost 1M monthly tracked users at peak times they'll baulk at a bill that will likely run over $100k per year just for this function.

Comment: @DannyBishop While I have not implemented it myself, I believe you could use the open source offering from Segment. Might be worth a look: https://github.com/segmentio/analytics.js